# Problem with Typescript (React-Native) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'typeAnnotation')

Tags: typescript, react-native, types, codegen

When I am trying to build my React Native (0.71.8 on New Arch) App with `npx react-native run-android` or when I am generating code with codegen from my android folder with `./gradlew generateCodegenArtifactsFromSchema --rerun-tasks`
I encounter this error :

`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'typeAnnotation')`.

I think this error is coming from this TypeScript who describes my Native Component:

```
import type {HostComponent} from 'react-native';
import type {ComponentType} from 'react';
import codegenNativeComponent from 'react-native/Libraries/Utilities/codegenNativeComponent';
import codegenNativeCommands from 'react-native/Libraries/Utilities/codegenNativeCommands';
import React from 'react';
import { Int32 } from 'react-native/Libraries/Types/CodegenTypes';


export interface NativeProps{
    filePath? : string;
    mapPath?: string; 
    mapSecretCode?: Int32; 
    mapHash?: string; 
    mapServerUrl?: string;
  }
  
export default codegenNativeComponent<NativeProps>(
    'RTNMapView'
  ) as HostComponent<NativeProps>;


interface NativeCommands {
  loadMapView: () => void;
  loadMapData: () => void;
  unloadMapView: () => void;
  unloadMapData: () => void;
  }
  

export const Commands: NativeCommands =
  codegenNativeCommands<NativeCommands>({
    supportedCommands: ['loadMapView','loadMapData','unloadMapView','unloadMapData'],
  });
```

Somehow I am not really sure what is causing this issue. I have only one other typescript file (which is my App), so I think the error is coming from the previous file.

At first I was thinking Int32 was the problem, but changing it didn't remove the issue.

I am not sure what is causing this issue.